# iOS: TableView scroll to section

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5

I have a UITableView that for section headers has dates. I would like to scroll to a section header when a users presses the 'Today' button. How would I scroll to a section based on the text in the section title?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597839/iphone-how-to-scroll-to-the-1st-cell-of-the-2nd-section-letting-the-header-of

Comment: @ConradShultz that would work if the date was always in the same section.

Comment: You will need to figure out the section for the date using your data model.  How you do this depends on how the model/data source is structured.  I thought you were just asking about the scrolling part.  Did you also need to know how to find the section index?

Comment: You are then going to need to update your question to describe your data model.  You definitely SHOULDN'T be storing dates as strings, so I assume you have some data structure containing NSDate instances or equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you explain your data model we can help you find the section index.  That is the key step.

Once you have it, you can use UITableView's -rectForHeaderInSection: method to obtain the CGRect corresponding to the section's header.  Then, as @oriolpons notes, you can use the enclosing scroll view's -scrollRectToVisible: method to actually scroll the table to the determined CGRect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
tableView scrollRectToVisible:
```

Try reading this post, I think it will help you.

[How do I scroll a UITableView to a section that contains no rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159821/how-do-i-scroll-a-uitableview-to-a-section-that-contains-no-rows)

Comment: I have that much but it doesn't help with finding the location of the section which contains today's date.

Comment: Mmm, the "bad" solution would be doing it programmatically... comparing all the sections with the section you want to scroll and and adding the height of all the cells to calculate the position you want to scroll... but I don't think that is the best solution

Comment: @oriolpons That approach would not, for example, account for header height and any padding.  "There's a method for that."